# Is a second comma necessary (or perhaps no comma should be used at all)?

Tags: commas

I am unsure of the proper comma usage in this part of a sentence contained in a text I am proofreading:
"The many, and at times quite explicit references to the people..."
I hesitate to add a comma after "explicit" (not really any parenthetical elements here)... but then perhaps no comma should be used at all?

Comment: As an aside, it looks parenthetical. I'd go with 2 commas or none.

Comment: It might help to give the entire sentence.

Comment: I agree with @Yosef Baskin; I'd add that the weight (largely length) of the ellipted continuation would influence my choice of offsetting commas or zero punctuation round the parenthetical.

Comment: Entire sentence: "The many, and at times quite explicit references to the people whose lives PARIS IS BURNING offered a glimpse into, renew the questions around documentary ethics, looking relations, and power that have long surrounded Livingston’s film." The comma after "into" seems awkward to me (at best); to reduce confusion, perhaps: The many – and at times quite explicit – references to the people into whose lives PARIS IS BURNING offered a glimpse, renew the questions around documentary ethics, looking relations, and power that have long surrounded Livingston’s film. Does that work?